# Visual Studio 2012 - SSL Download Error - Certificate Not Valid

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, ssis

Error: Download File Error: SSL certificate response obtained from the server was not valid. Cannot process the request.

Running a part of the SSIS job in Visual Studio (Download NPI File Task) we are getting and error shown above even though I have downloaded the cert from the website and installed it using MMC. I am attaching the code we are using in hope someone can help

````
        {
            bool repeat = true;
            string tmpFileName = null;

            try
            {

                string npiWebAddress = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::NPI_File_Web_Address"].Value;
                string inBoxPath = Path.Combine((string)Dts.Variables["$Project::CSV_File_Root_Folder"].Value, (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::Inbox_Folder"].Value);
                string zipFilePath = Path.Combine((string)Dts.Variables["$Project::CSV_File_Root_Folder"].Value, (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::Zip_Files_Folder"].Value);
                
                Directory.CreateDirectory(inBoxPath);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(zipFilePath);

                DateTime monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).AddDays(-7);
                DateTime sunday = monday.AddDays(6);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(npiWebAddress))
                {
                    Dts.Events.FireInformation(105, "DownloadNpiFile", "NPI Download Disabled, NPI_File_Web_Address is blank", "", 0, ref repeat);
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                    return;
                }

                // reserve a temp file to hold the downloaded zip file
                tmpFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

                // first try to download a monthly full listing zip file
                bool fileDownloaded = DownloadMonthlyFile(sunday, npiWebAddress, zipFilePath, tmpFileName);
                if(fileDownloaded)
                {
                    UnzipCsvFile(monday, sunday, true, tmpFileName, inBoxPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    // try to download a weekly update zip file if we did not download a monthly file
                    fileDownloaded = DownloadWeeklyUpdateFile(monday, sunday, npiWebAddress, zipFilePath, tmpFileName);
                    if(fileDownloaded)
                    {
                        UnzipCsvFile(monday, sunday, false, tmpFileName, inBoxPath);
                    }
                }

                // move the zip file to the network share if a file was downloaded
                if (fileDownloaded && _zipFileFullPath != null)
                {
                    File.Move(tmpFileName, _zipFileFullPath);
                    tmpFileName = null;
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(1000, ex.Source, ex.Message, "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
            finally
            {
                if(tmpFileName != null)
                {
                    File.Delete(tmpFileName);
                }
            }
        } ```
````

Comment: Are there any warnings when you navigate to the site and look at the certificate?

Comment: None at all, I am able to go to the website and download the file manually.